# Parsing ranges into discrete values, in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

User will provide a list containing ranges.
I need to convert it to a list of discrete values.

For example

## Input

```
host[1-5],host7,host[13-15]
```

## Output

```
host1,host2,host3,host4,host5,host7,host13,host14,host15.
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hosts=($(echo "host[1-5],host7,host[13-15]" | sed 's/,/ /g'))
string=""
for h in ${hosts[@]}; do 
  if [[ ! ${h//[^0-9]/} =~ ^[0-9]$ ]]; then
      for i in $(seq ${h//[^0-9]/ }); do 
        string+="${h%[*}$i,"
      done
  else
    string+="$h,"
  fi
done

echo "${string%,}"
```

Output:

```
host1,host2,host3,host4,host5,host7,host13,host14,host15,
```

Comment: hi, this answer almost works. but it fails if i give an input like so
host[9-10],host15,host[23-32]
it has something to do with regex handing single count host with double digits. i assume triple digits would also fail. I am trying to work it out. But i am pretty weak in regex. This part of the script is just for user experience so one doesnt have to input a hostlist from host1,host2,host9,....host128.

Answer (score -1):

If you change your input to

```
hostlist=host{{1..5},7,{13..15}}
```

then

```
eval echo $hostlist | tr ' ' ,
host1,host2,host3,host4,host5,host7,host13,host14,host15
```

Comment: Be careful using `eval`: It can result in you executing arbitrary instructions. The provider of the data can do what ever they want to your account.

Comment: Yes, sanitize that input before use! Wash your hands 20 seconds also.

Answer (score -1):

Try `bash`'s "Parameter expansion / pattern substitution"

```
$ hostlist=host[1-5],host7,host[13-15]
$ H1=${hostlist//[/{}
$ H2=${H1//]/\}}
$ H3=${H2//,/ }
$ H4=$(eval echo ${H3//-/..})
$ H5=${H4// /,}
$ echo "$H5"
host1,host2,host3,host4,host5,host7,host13,host14,host15
```

Comment: Be careful using eval: It can result in you executing arbitrary instructions. The provider of the data can do what ever they want to your account.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I'm well aware of the `eval` connotations. While I appreciate corrections / amendments and learn from those, I'd like to learn from you how `eval echo` in a variable assignment can execute arbitrary instructions.

Comment: @RidiC The warning is not for you. It if for all those that come after us.